Managing pg_wal on postgresql 14
I have to maintain our postgresql 14 on production level. We dont have any replica, and when I check our pg_wal is taking 2.7T storage, because the person in charge before me didnt activate archive_command. So, I activate the archive_command, and I set wal_keep_size = 80GB.
But the storage didnt reduce significantly, my pg_wal's size still at 2.7T. And my archive folder is 195GB, at first I manually clean file in archive folder, with pg_archivecleanup command on shell, but it is taking so long to free up the space too, and is it okay to do that?
Then, I try activate archive_cleanup_command, but I am not sure it will works/not.
Is it correct to manually clean archive folder? Do I need to backup this archive?
This is result of select * from pg_stat_archiver;

Result of select * from pg_replication_slots;


If you don't have any replicas, why do you have an archiving turned on in the first place?  Maybe your archive_command is failing or just slow, check the log file or the archive itself

pg_wal is not the archive (unless you have your archive a very misleading name) , it is the live WAL directory.

@jjanes sorry i think i dont describe my problem correctly, so my archiving command is work, when i check the folder for archive there is file in there, but it seems my pg_wal size is not decreasing. Is it okay to delete file on archive folder?

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314260/wal-files-management, over on [dba.se] (where, arguably, this question should be too) covers this directly.

If I read this question correctly, you set up an archive_command to decrease storage use? That's not how that works. archive_command is called when a log segment is ready to copy to a backup store, but if you aren't keeping backups in a way that calls for being able to replay old segments then you don't need to set it up; and if you are keeping backups, then you need to make a new full backup periodically so you can delete archived segments from before that backup was started. Which is all to say that archive retention depends on your backup strategy and you're not describing it.

...but if you're keeping excessive content in the live transaction log directory, as opposed to the archive, that's a different problem and needs a different solution. Certainly don't just go deleting anything; see the linked duplicate over on the [dba.se] to figure out which direction to start with.

@CharlesDuffy thanks, I already read that, but I still dont get it, I already set my wal_keep_size=80GB but why my pg_wal still in 2.7T size? Then if I cant delete pg_wal, how I can decrease storage use by pg_wal?

You read it, but could you please edit your question to show the results from following the debugging steps it recommends? That means select * from pg_stat_archiver; and select * from pg_replication_slots; to start. And do clarify if you're trying to have any backup solution configured, and if so what that is.

@CharlesDuffy thanks, I edited my question with the result from the queries. We regularly do pg_dump once a month.

Okay, so periodic pg_dump but no attempts to support point-in-time recovery?

Anyhow -- that replication slot looks like your problem. See wal_status extended -- that means it's keeping WAL segments it would otherwise be ready to throw away.

See How to disable replication slot on postgres to clean it up.

hai @CharlesDuffy thanks for the assistance, it was because replication slot with extended status. and because we do not need backup using pg_wal (we already use backup vm) we deactivate  archieve pg_wal. At first, archieving process still on but after we change path archieve to empty string, finally we can stop the process, and our storage is safe now. (sorry if my english sounds weird, because english is my second language).

Even Charles Duffy pointed out where the problem is , and solution as well.
I would like to summarize and make you understand easily.
As following your question , you do not have replica but, somehow it exists.
Replication slots table shows replication server exists and it logically connected.  This logical replication works based on wal, when DML occured wal sender process send to replica server after logical decoding.
Wal sender should send WAL to replica server by logical replication setting. but something went wrong. so pg_wal is keeping until 2.7T

Clarify the client that supposed to be using this replication slot
Drop the replication slots if this client is no longer needed


yup as state by Charles Duffy it was bcose replication slot. Thanks.
